Can I annotate a strategy-pattern class-factory using JSDoc?
Essentially I have the following inheritance chain:
Chainable -> Strategy -> Actions

Actions are used at the call-site returning a chainable API:
await actionMaker()
  .action1()
  .action2()
  .run();

run comes from Chainable, and action1 and action2 could come from either Strategy or Actions. The "action methods" essentially get pushed to an array, and run executes them in a Promise.
But the code actually looks more like this:
// Chainable:

class Chainable {
  enqueue(fn) { this.queue.push(fn); return this; }
  run() { return Promise_that_runs_everything; }
}

// Strategies:

class platformStrategy1 extends Chainable {
  action1() {
    return this.enqueue(() => {
      /* action1 implementation for platform 1 */ 
    }) 
  }
}

class platformStrategy2 extends Chainable {
  action1() {
    return this.enqueue(() => {
      /* action1 implementation for platform 2 */ 
    }) 
  }
}

// Actions:

function actionMaker(strategy) {
  class _Action extends strategy {
    action2() { return this.action1(); }
  }
  return new _Action();
}

// Call site:

await actionMaker(platformStrategy1)
//                ^_______________^
  .action1()
  .action2()
  .run();

So I can pass in different strategies depending on the platform I want to run the actions on, since different platforms require different implementations of the actions.
Methods in Actions will only call methods in Strategy, and the strategies hold the implementation details. All methods return this, except for run which returns a Promise that executes them.
TypeScript is not an option, so my question is: can I annotate something like this using JSDoc?

It's not really clear how the implementation of action2 or platformStrategy1 would look like. Can you expand your example, please?

@Bergi Thanks, I've added a bit more detail. All action methods either run enqueue (or methods that call it) and return this.
